# Divergent or convergent integral

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I have the next integral:

$$\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{x^\mu}\,\text{d}x$$

I would like to know how to determine whether it's convergent or divergent according to the values given to $\mu$.

I can't really figure out how to proceed and how the procedure would look like. 
Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: That you don't know the answer seems contradicted by [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/236617/).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be missunderstood, what I aim in this case is to know wether the integral is divergent or convergent for the different possible values of #μ not how to get the other expression that appeared in the question you have just mentioned. Thank you very much for your time @did.

Comment: But you stated exactly *w[h]ether the integral is divergent or convergent for the different possible values of #μ* in this other question... Well, whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu = 1$, obviously integral diverges. $\displaystyle \int_a^{+\infty} \frac 1x dx = \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \ln x - \ln a \rightarrow \infty$. If $\mu \neq 1$ then $\displaystyle \int_a^{+\infty} x^{-\mu} dx = \frac 1{-\mu + 1} \left(\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} x^{-\mu + 1} - a^{-\mu + 1}\right)$. In this case, integral diverges or converges depending on the value of limit. If $-\mu + 1 < 0 \Rightarrow \mu > 1$ limit exists and is finite, so integral converges. For all other values of $\mu$ integral diverges. So

$\mu > 1$ converges

$\mu \le 1$ diverges

Comment: All this is true considering $a>0$